# Location of the android sdk has not been setup in the preferences in mac os?

Tags: android

I am installing the Android SDK along with Eclipse in mac os. Whenever I try to start a new project development I get an error **location of the android sdk has not been setup in the preferences**

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Did any of the answers work?  I'm experience a similar issue.

Comment: @ScottBiggs, i not proceed my work in android in mac after this. sorry i haven't any idea yet. But i guess 1st answer Pasha given may be right.

Comment: This worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869929/update-android-sdk-tool-to-22-0-4latest-version-from-22-0-1

Answer (score 42):

Hi try this in eclipse: Window - Preferences - Android - SDK Location and setup SDK path.

Comment: @Pasha, i installing all in mac os 2nd directory, i thing you given me solution accordingly windows os.

Comment: This solution will fit every OS. You have to indicate to the Android Eclipse Plugin where the SDK is installed. To do so, follow Pasha directions.

Comment: Android Eclipse plugin installed? Check.

In Eclipse, go to
Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager -> Installed Packages -> Update All

Comment: And what about eclipse preferences? Did you setup SDK path?

Comment: yes, i set up sdk path. I confused and frustrated what wrong going with me.

Comment: i am following process video tutorial "Android Development on the Mac - Getting Started" on youtube.com.

Answer (score 21):

I got this message after updating eclipse platform-tools and tools from the SDK Manager and then it was impossible to update the SDK path because I had an old version of ADT plugin.

Whenever you get this error message in a prompt right after eclipse loaded, you should do the following:

1. Go to Help - Install new software
2. Click on Available software sites
3. Delete the link http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
4. Reboot eclipse
5. Go to Help - Install new software
6. In the box "Work with" add http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ again
7. Install ADT and accept whatever that prompts.

This is how my problem with this message got solved.

Answer (score 11):

I saw this error after updating the Android SDK to r17.  The solution was to go to Help -> Update and get the latest version of the Android SDK to match.

Comment: Im having the same issue after updating my android sdk but not quite sure which caused which.  Im running Eclipse Indigo on Mac OSX 10.7.4

Answer (score 8):

I experienced this problem and fixed it by updating to the latest Android SDK Tools which in my case was 20.0.3

I am running Mac OSX Lion 10.7.4

If ever you encounter errors while updating the SDK Tools try deleting

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
from the "Available Software Sites" in Eclipse, and adding it again.

Comment: This fixed my problem with "parseSdkContent failed com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.createInstance". This was for ADT v21.0.1

Answer (score 5):

If you have not installed plugin for eclipse, install it first.

If the plugin is installed, setup preferences: "Eclipse">"Preferences...", in left column choose "Android"(do not expand list, just choose root element), and first preference will be "SDK Location".

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem on Eclipse Juno.

No "Welcome page" appeared, I could not create a project, compilation didn't work and "Graphical layout" didn't work.

I have fixed it:
Window > Preferences > General > Startup and shutdown:
Check "Android development toolkit"

Reestart Eclipse.

Of course you have to be configured this:
Window - Preferences - Android - SDK Location and setup SDK path.

Answer (score 4):

Simply create this folder:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\android-sdk\tools
```

and then from `Window -> Preferences -> Android`, put this path:

```
 C:\Users\xxxxx\android-sdk
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was then prompted with the Android SDK Manager which downloaded the correct files.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I was trying to upgrade from ADT 20.0.x to ADT 23.0.x on Eclipse Indigo.

To fix the issue, I had to uninstall the ADT plugin (remove feature) from Eclipse, then reinstall the newer versions.

This maybe done by going to `Help->Install New Software`. Then at the bottom of the page, click `What is already installed?`

All what is left now is to install the newer versions as usual from `help->Install New Software`.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me; because without removing the old Android stuff, it would show a "conflict" message with the new files about to be downloaded and the old files. Bunch of Eclipse BS I think !!

Comment: note: I uninstalled: DDMS, Dev Tools, Hierachry Viewer, Native Dev Tools, Traceview, Tracer for OPenGL ES

Answer (score 1):

there are many things which can cause this error. For example, I 
imported google api from the android SDK Manager and that is when I 
got this same error. Eclipse broke down on me. I could not even create 
a new android project.

To fix this, I went to help - Install New Software... - from the "work with"
drop-down box I selected http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ - 
I then check marked "Developer Tools" and hit the Next button.
I then followed the prompts and it basically did a re-install. It took less
than 5 minutes. That resolved the error.

Now Im back up and running, and I got the lastest version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

i tried everything/....but only this thing worked for me:

To fix this, I went to help - Install New Software... - from the "work with" drop-down box I selected http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ - I then check marked "Developer Tools" and hit the Next button. I then followed the prompts and it basically did a re-install. It took less than 5 minutes. That resolved the error.

Now Im back up and running, and I got the lastest version of Eclipse.

Thanks a lot Nadir

Comment: This answer has the best aproach to the problem I had. When Window - Preferences - Android doest not allow you to modify the SDK path, you should reinstall ADT plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

Step 1.) Go to https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php?release=kepler and download appropriate Eclipse version.

Step 2.) Extract downloaded zip file in appropriate location. In this tutorial, I have downloaded and installed it under program files.

Step 3.) Right click on eclipse.exe file and send shortcut to desktop.

Step 4.) Double click on eclipse shortcut from desktop and select appropriate location to create your workspace.

Step 5.) Navigate to Window > Preferences. This should open Preferences window.

Step 6.) On the left hand side page expend “Java” and click on “Installed JREs”

Step 7.) Click Add. It will open “Add JRE” dialog. Select “Standard VM” and click Next.

Step 8.) For “JRE home”  select “Direcotry…”. This will open “Browse for folder” dialog. Select the location where your JDK is installed. NOTE: MAKE SURE THAT ITS x64 AS WELL, AS WE ARE USING 64-BIT VERSION OF ECLIPSE.

Step 9.) If you have selected proper location, it will show JDK version in JRE name and it will display “JRE system libraries”.

Step 10.) Click finish. Now your JDK is properly pointed as “Installed JREs”.

Step 11.) Select checkbox unchecked before name of your JDK name.

Click ok and you’re done. You are now using JDK as “Installed JREs”

Read complete procedure at below location.

https://softwaretestingboard.com/qna/4/how-do-i-map-android-sdk-after-eclipse-plugin-is-installed#axzz4wM3UEZtq

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Android SDK path by running the SDK Manager.  Once the window comes up the path is displayed at the top.  For me it was hiding in AddData (Windows).  You can then set the path in Eclipse by going Window > Preferences > Android > and set SDK Location.

Answer (score 0):

If you already installed in your eclipse you can solve this problem below,

Go to Windows -> Install New Software and find your android plugin address

Check all lists and re-install your android plugin for eclipse

I solved it like this

Answer (score 0):

It is very irritating problem... i found one simple solution...that is
eclipse->help->Install new software

now u see "work with"field...below this fields u observe on link called 
"available software sites"...click on this link..then open one window...here u find out some location address..... delete wrong locations and then add perfect location to install/update location. then click on ok button... then ur problem is solved....

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to arise from new versions of android sdk the solution that worked fine for me was to go to help->check for updates and let that finish once all software in eclipse updated it all seems to work fine. I was using juno and the latest sdk, which I upgraded outside eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem.
the solution is...Copy the link http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
then in eclipse go to

Help > Install New Software > Add(work with) > past the link on locations > ok > select all > next

this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you already setup location in preferences, but see that error, try to create folder "add-ons" in your sdk folder

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem in windows, the reason is always displayed at the top of the window(where you browse for the location)

Comment: this should be a comment rather than an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is, how I've handled this issue (Mac OS X 10.8.4):

1) Because I previously have installed Android Studio the sdk located here:
**Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk**

You can dig into Android Studio.app folder by hitting "Show package contents" in context menu

2) Simply copy the "sdk" folder to another location and write it down to Eclipse preferences. 
Because I couldn't find how to properly add adress like "/Android Studio.app/sdk" (folder with .app extension) to Eclipse preferences.

I know that this solution is not smooth and best, but it works (at least for me). And I've tried all advices in this theme, and installed the ADT from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ before, but the error window have kept appearing every time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: when click on the "Opens the Android SDK Manager", a pop out error message says “Location of the Android SDK has not been setup in the preference”. 
The delete and add again update address in "install new software" doesn't work for me.

I went to the ../android/android-sdk-windows and click the SDK Manager.exe. This works for me.

So I think after I updated the SDK, the eclipse cannot trigger the SDK Manager currently. But it can run by itself outside of eclipse.