# Update Android SDK Tool to 22.0.4(Latest Version) from 22.0.1

Tags: android, sdk, adt

I want to Update my Android SDK Tool from 22.0.1 to  22.0.4

I also Have ADT installed, but could not update the SDK Tool to  22.0.4

I am facing the following issue :

```
Download interrupted: Read timed out issue.
```

Below is the screen shot while updating SDK :

[image]

Answer (score 178, accepted):

I viewed the [Eclipse ADT documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) and found out the way to get around this issue. I was able to Update My SDK Tool to 22.0.4 (Latest Version).

> **Solution is:** First Update ADT to 22.0.4(Latest version) and then Update SDK Tool to
>   22.0.4(Latest Version)

The above link says,

> **ADT 22.0.4** is designed for use with **SDK Tools r22.0.4**. If you haven't
>   already installed SDK Tools **r22.0.4** into your SDK, use the Android SDK
>   Manager to do so

What I had to do was update my ADT to 22.0.4 (Latest Version) and then I was able to update SDK tool to 22.0.4. I thought only SDK Tool has been updated not ADT, so I was updating the SDK Tool with Older ADT Version (22.0.1).

**How to Update your ADT to Latest Version**

1. In Eclipse go to `Help`
2. `Install New Software` ---> `Add`
3. inside `Add Repository` write the Name: `ADT` (or whatever you want)
4. and Location: `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
5. after loading you should get `Developer Tools` and `NDK Plugins`
6. check both if you want to use the Native Developer Kit (NDK) in the future or check `Developer Tool` only
7. click `Next`
8. `Finish`

Comment: sounds like a stupid question but where should i download ADT 21.1.0 from? ok, i just found it on http://www.softpedia.com but that a pain of a site, all ads. is there no official place?

Comment: i just download a whole new adt from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download seems to be the best way

Comment: Please make sure that you use the **HTTPS** version of the site. Do not use the built-in `Android Developer Tools Update Site` from eclipse (which uses HTTP). Otherwise, it will result to an error mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544071/an-error-occurred-while-collecting-items-to-be-installed-access-is-denied) `(An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context)`

Comment: I want to second steveh's suggestion. Trying to update the Developer Tools manually breaks adt's integration. Downloading from scratch seems to work though.

Comment: I second steveh's comment. When I followed Bhavesh's steps, it broke the adt integration for me as well. Re-downloading from the android dev website works like a charm (you might have to reset the Eclipse workspace, but that's about it)

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me when I got the problem today. Eclipse really is a retarded tool.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Eclipse complains that each package is already installed. If it's already installed, why doesn't it use it instead of complaining that it's not there?

Comment: I couldn't get things to work through Eclipse no matter what I tried, so on Windows ran this command first from console window, then returned to Eclipse afterwards and was finally able to update: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools>android.bat update sdk --no-ui

Answer (score 3):

I'm on OSX, I was using Android Studio instead of ADT and I had this issue, my problem was being behind a proxy with authentication, for what ever reason, In Android SDK Manager Window, under Preferences -> Others,  I needed to **uncheck** the

> "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://..."

Also, there was no place to put the proxy credentials, but it will prompt you for them.

Comment: I would urge others to try **unchecking** this option too as it helped me from on a mac behind a firewall. No idea why, but saves me pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to go to Window -> Android SDK Manager -> Packages -> Reload to fetch latest updates and then update the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, I tried the below solution and it worked for me 
In Android SDK Manager Window, click on Tools->Options-> under "Others", check `"Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://..."`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this http://tools.android.com/preview-channel ?
Download preview channel. After that, install ADT Preview.

Comment: Thanks for your Quick Reply but could not help me out.

Answer (score 0):

run **Android SDK Manager** as administrator.
that solved my problem

> > sudo **android**