# Eclipse ADT Plugin crashed after updating to version 22.0

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm having serious issues trying to work with Eclipse.

First, I downloaded both Eclipse and ADT Bundle, but it seems that I didn't need to download Eclipse, I can just use the one that comes with the ADT download, is that right? I'm just explaining that to make sure that's not the reason I'm facing problems.

After downloading ADT version 21, I tried to link it with the sdk path, but there was a message saying that I must update the ADT to the 22nd version.

I did that following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869929/update-android-sdk-tool-to-22-0-0latest-version-from-21-1-0?answertab=votes#tab-top) instructions and, after restarting the program, it appeared like that:

[image: ADT appearence]

I cannot do anything, the software seems broken. Anybody know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, I think I did something that may have fixed the problem. Yet, its worthy to share:

1. Open you `ADT Bundle` folder
2. In `eclipse` folder, look for `eclipse.ini` file
3. Open this file with the Notepad
4. In the `Declipse.buildId` field, replace the version value with this one: **v22.0.0-675183**
5. Save and reopen the software.

It's "working". I have to open two instances of Eclipse for it to work, and I still couldn't do any apps.
Still looking for help.