# Got an Error when Updating my ADT from 21.1 to 22

Tags: android

First, Hello everyone. I'm a new on this site.

I've got an error when I update my ADT (in eclipse) from 21.1 to 22.0...

When I re-open the program, I got a white blank page and ADT shows this message on the page:

```
Could not open the editor: No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor
```

I tried to follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653656/eclipse-adt-plugin-crashed-after-updating-to-version-22-0), and we got a slightly different problem, and the program still crashes.

Can anyone help me to fix my problems? Since I'm new in here, I am not be able to post a picture.

Thanks.

Comment: You can upload a screenshot elsewhere on the Internet, then link to it from your question.