# Unable to download android support library revision 13 using android sdk manager

Tags: android

Sir, i am new to android application development environment. I can not download android support library revision 13 using sdk manager. Giving error message like: "Download interrupted:Read time out" Please help....

Comment: Try this if you haven't already. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OlnCfxuOCYk%5B1-25-false%5D
and this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869929/update-android-sdk-tool-to-22-0-0latest-version-from-21-1-0

Comment: First of all i want to thank you for your time. But these are not real solution for my problem. If you have any other solution(is there any way to download android support library r13 manually) please share with me. I can't create new android project. I am stuck with eclipse 'JUNO'.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I am not using any proxy. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to android. Simply download adt bundle (eclipse + android sdk configured) from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Comment: Yes i am new in Android. But i have sdk tool. What's the problem with sdk??? Why i need adt bundle???

Comment: ADT bundle is already configured environment for android development. Sometime problems occur while configuration ADT plugin with eclipse. That's why android provide this configured sdk and eclipse.

Comment: Thank you 'Adnan'. I will surely download ADT bundle but before doing so if you have any other solution(i am unable to create new android project in eclipse juno) related to my problem, please share with me. I will be the happiest person on my own. Thank you again.

Comment: – GUNTLET - First Update ADT to 22.0.0 and Then you can Update SDK Tool to 22.0 and download other files eg support library.

How to Update your ADT?

    In Eclipse go to Help ---> Install new software --> Add
    inside Add Repository write the plugin name eg ADT or any you want--->
    In Location paste this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ --->
    after loading Developer Tools and NDK Plugins
    check both --->
    click Next --->
    Finish--->Thats it