# ADT not working after update to v22

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

My ADT stopped working after updating to version 22. I have tried using the alternate Google repository for the tools, which didn't work, as well as removing other potentially conflicting Eclipse plugins. I also tried deleting the folders that contained ADT features from my ~/.eclipse dir. I am running Eclipse Juno SR2. I have made sure that my Android SDKs are also up-to-date.

Below is a snippet from my Eclipse logfile after updating:

```
!SESSION 2013-06-01 19:19:14.925 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-01 19:19:19.431
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: adt.actionSet.wizards

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-01 19:19:19.433
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: adt.actionSet.avdManager

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-01 19:19:19.433
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: adt.actionSet.lint

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-01 19:19:19.433
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: adt.actionSet.refactorings

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2013-06-01 19:19:20.802
!MESSAGE Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms/icons/logcat.png".
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms/icons/logcat.png".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.resolve(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:75)
    (long stack trace continues...)
```

I appreciate any suggestions you may have.

Comment: Well, I guess deleting the ~/.eclipse folder and re-creating it also works...

Answer (score 0):

Got that error message after [updating ADT from v21.1.0 to 22.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869929/update-android-sdk-tool-to-22-0-0latest-version-from-21-1-0).
Checked some post here, and got ADT running again

Here's what I did:

1. If you still have ADT installation files with you, copy all files/folders (except plugins) from eclipse directory, into ADT eclipse location
2. Do not copy "plugins" folder over to ADT eclipse location.

thanks