# How to install old version of Android build tools from command line?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, build-tools

I am installing android SDK to create an automated build server. I got into a problem where many Gradle-based Android projects I manage rely on different build tools version. Some of the projects still requiring old build-tools version (e.g. v19.1.0).

My android-sdk package was downloaded when build-tools version 20 has just released, so that's the only version available to download via `android update sdk -u --filter build-tools`.

I have tried to invoke `android update sdk -u --filter build-tools-19.1.0` but it didn't work. Is there an easy way to install old version of Android build tools from command line?

Note: installing via GUI is not possible

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Assuming you have downloaded the Android SDK for linux, you have two options to update from command line.

**Download using *android* tool from the sdk**

Instead of running the android sdk manager with a GUI, you also have an option to run in headless mode. You just need to specify `-u` (or `--no-ui`) flag.

To list packages available for installation or upgrade:

```
$ cd android-sdk-linux
$ ./tools/android list sdk --all
Refresh Sources:
  (...)
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  (...)
Packages available for installation or update: 166
   1- Android SDK Tools, revision 24.4.1
   2- Android SDK Tools, revision 25.0.9 rc10
   3- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.1
   4- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 24 rc1
   5- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24 rc1
   6- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.2
   7- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.1
   8- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23 (Obsolete)
  (...)
 162- Google Play Billing Library, revision 5
 163- Google Play Licensing Library, revision 2
 164- Android Auto API Simulators, revision 1
 165- Google Web Driver, revision 2
 166- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer), revision 6.0.1
```

To download specific packages you need to specify the number of the item you want to install from the list in the following command:

```
$ ./tools/android update sdk -u -a -t [NO_OF_ITEM_TO_BE_INSTALLED]
```

Example: if I wanted to install Android SDK build tools revision 23.0.1, I would type in:

```
$ ./tools/android update sdk -u -a -t 7
```

**Manual download**

As not every package (especially the old ones) is listed when you do `android sdk list`, you can also download things manually. You can manually open the XML file that is shown when during `android sdk list` - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml

You can find there links to various types of things to download, e.g:

- ADK
- http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-XX.0.0.zip
- SDK Tools
- http://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_rXX-linux.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_rXX-windows.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_rXX-macosx.zip
- Platform Tools
- http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_rXX-linux.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_rXX-windows.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_rXX-macosx.zip
- Build Tools
- http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_rXX-linux.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_rXX-windows.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_rXX-macosx.zip
- Platforms
- http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-XX.zip

To manually download e.g. version 19.0.1 of build tools

```
$ cd android-sdk-linux/build-tools
$ wget http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r19.0.1-linux.zip
$ unzip build-tools_r19.0.1-linux.zip
$ mv android-4.4.2 19.0.1
$ rm build-tools_r19.0.1-linux.zip
```

**Side note (ubuntu):**

If you're running debian/ubuntu 64-bit, to run `aapt` you will need to install additional packages:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

If you're running CentOs (RedHat), to run `aapt` you will need to install additional packages:

```
sudo yum install zlib.i686 libstd++.i686
```

While running `aapt`, if you get an error with GLIBC 2.14 and you dont wont to upgrade your locale GLIBC. Then u need to download the following packages for sdk (build-tool, platform-tool) :

build-tool : http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r23.0.2-linux.zip

platform-tool : https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip

Comment: you said that after downloading Android SDK, first we need to run "android update sdk -u". when doing it with no filters, then it will download huge mount of Gigs.... all i need is a specific version....

Comment: @DoronShai I updated the answer, hope it's complete right now!

Comment: @wtekiela You "side note" was extremely helpful. Thanks! It would be a popular question in its own right.

Comment: Amazing. I did the above when Nox App Player only working with 4.4.2 (API 19)

Comment: How do we install the Build tools in windows without using android studio?

Answer (score 7):

What you want is to be able to obtain the same functionality of the SDK Manager GUI in a command line.

Issue this command to query all available packages from the repository. 
The query will return the packages with a index number on the left.

```
[rgulia@xinu ~]$ android list sdk --all 
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
  Validate XML
  Parse XML
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  …
  Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
  Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
  Packages available for installation or update: 138
  1- Android SDK Tools, revision 24.1.2
  2- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 22
  3- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 22.0.1
  4- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 22 (Obsolete)
  5- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.2
  ….
```

You can use a grep command to narrow your search. For example:

```
[rgulia@xinu ~]$ android list sdk --all | grep -i tools | grep 21
   5- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.2
   6- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.1 (Obsolete)
   7- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1 (Obsolete)
   8- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.0.2 (Obsolete)
   9- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.0.1 (Obsolete)
  10- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21 (Obsolete)
```

Finally, install the desired package by supplying its index number in this command.

```
[rgulia@xinu ~]$ android update sdk -u -a -t 5
```

The options have this meaning:

```
-u (--no-ui)  # Headless mode
-a (--all)    # Includes all packages, included the obsolete ones
-t (--filter) # in this example we have filtered by package index, i.e. 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question, I have just found that one of the best way to achieve my goal is by using [SDK manager Gradle plugin by Jake Wharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin).

It's as simple as adding Gradle plugin. Any required SDK packages will be installed on demand to SDK location specified in `local.properties`.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

This approach works great especially in headless CI environment. Just don't forget to add `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable just in case you don't have `local.properties` already (which most likely happens on CI environment)

Answer (score 2):

Based on: [How to install Android SDK Build Tools on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963508/how-to-install-android-sdk-build-tools-on-the-command-line) and others here is my version:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

installAndroidSdk() {
    local url=http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.3-linux.tgz

    sudo apt-get install -y lib32stdc++6 lib32z1

    # Install android SDK
    (
        cd /opt

        curl -o android.tgz -sL $url

        tar xzf android.tgz

        mv android-sdk-linux/ android

        rm android.tgz

        echo "export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android" > /etc/profile.d/android.sh
        echo "export PATH=\$PATH:\$ANDROID_HOME/tools:\$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools" >> /etc/profile.d/android.sh
        source /etc/profile.d/android.sh

        android list sdk --all --extended > /tmp/android-skds

        modules=( platform-tools build-tools-22.0.1 android-22 )
        for module in ${modules[@]}; do
            moduleId=$(less /tmp/android-skds | sed -n "s/id: \(.*\) or \"$module\"/\1/p")
            if [[ ! -z "$moduleId" ]]; then
                expect -c "
                    set timeout -1   ;
                    spawn android update sdk -u -a -t $moduleId;
                    expect { 
                        \"Do you accept the license\" { exp_send \"y\r\" ; exp_continue }
                        eof
                    }
                "
            else
                echo "[WARNING] - $module was not installed."
            fi
        done

        echo "export PATH=\$PATH:\$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/22.0.1" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/android.sh

        rm -f /tmp/android-skds
        sudo apt-get install -y android-tools-adb
    )
    return $?
}
```