# Issue Loading Android SDK Tools

Tags: android, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, android-sdk-tools

Please whenever I try to get Android's sdk list with the following command, `android list sdk -a` I get the bellow listed error.

```
 Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
 Failed to fetch URL
 https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason:
 File not found
 Fetched Add-ons List successfully
 Refresh Sources
 Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
 Failed to fetch URL
 https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml, reason: File not found
 Refresh Sources:
 Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
 Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml, reason: File not found
```

Answer (score 0):

So i found a manual work around for installing the SDks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016770/how-to-install-old-version-of-android-build-tools-from-command-line)

You can find there links to various types of things to download, e.g:

**ADK**

```
http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-XX.0.0.zip
```

**SDK Tools**

```
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_rXX-linux_x86.zip
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_rXX-windows.zip
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_rXX-macosx.zip
```

**Platform Tools**

```
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_rXX-linux_x86.zip
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_rXX-windows.zip
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_rXX-macosx.zip
```

**Build Tools**

```
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_rXX-linux.zip
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_rXX-windows.zip
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_rXX-macosx.zip
```

**Platforms**

```
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-XX.zip
```

**To manually download e.g. version 23.0.1 of build tools**

```
$ cd android-sdk-linux/build-tools
$ wget http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip
$ unzip build-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip
$ mv android-6.0 23.0.1
$ rm build-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip
```

**Side note (ubuntu):**

If you're running **debian/ubuntu 64-bit**, to run `aapt` you will need to install additional packages:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```