# Is there a method to install android SDK manually?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I have Android Studio, without Android SDK.
For some reason, I cannot install android SDK from the software.
I want to download Android SDK from the browser.
Does anybody know how to do it? Or, where does Android Studio download Android SDK from?

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/installing-android-sdk-tools#:~:text=You%20will%20need%20to%20download,for%20your%20build%20machine%20OS.&text=Unzip%20and%20place%20the%20contents%20within%20your%20home%20directory.

Comment: Thank you, pskink. However, it seems I can only download commandline-tools, and I need to download sdk tools from internet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26365848/2252830