# How do I resolve this when trying to release Android package

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk, msbuild, xamarin-studio

When trying to do a release build in `Xamarin Studio` I get the following error:
I've got version 21 of the sdk installed. I've set my minimum and target android version in project options to `version 21`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error XA0000: Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com. Reason: Could not find SDK platform directory 'C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-19'. Are --sdk-dir and --sdk-version set appropriately? (XA0000) ([projectname]) monodroid
```

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Are you missing android sdk? Try adding android-19 too have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963508/how-to-install-android-sdk-build-tools-on-the-command-line

Answer (score -2):

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12938

Looks like you are using starter edition, or have not logged in xmarin studio properly. If you have done so, try to relaunch xamarin studio. If you have starter edition, try do decrease size of you binary to be less then 8mb