# Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-23.0.3'Warning: The package filter removed all packages

Tags: android-studio

Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-23.0.3'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.[This is the screen shot of the the error message that I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQkJf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, that Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.3 are installed. For this click Tools->Android->SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> check Show Package Details.[image] If it is not installed, install this. If problem is not solved, try to downgrade `buildToolsVersion` to `"23.0.2"` in app's module gradle. Sync project, after that, again upgrade to `"23.0.3"`. It works for me.

Comment: The solution that worked for me is at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963508/how-to-install-android-sdk-build-tools-on-the-command-line