# Android sdk tools standalone installer

Tags: android

Is there any possibility to download Android sdk standalone installer - with SDK Manager - without Android Studio.
I need it for to develop apps outside Android Studio.Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Try something  like http://www.techspot.com/downloads/5425-android-sdk.html or follow an eclipse tutorial.

Answer (score 24):

[Go to the Android SDK tools download page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)  - "Get just the command line tools". Download, unzip, and run `bin/sdkmanager` to download whatever platform(s) you need.

For more details see also

- https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager
- [How to install Android SDK Build Tools on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963508/how-to-install-android-sdk-build-tools-on-the-command-line)

Comment: Many thanks. I knew about them but did not know to use them.

Comment: No worries. Be sure to mark this question as answered if this answer helped you.

Comment: I didn't see the installation GUI.

Comment: @OnurBaskirt What error (if any) are you getting when you run `sdkmanager`?

Comment: @OnurBaskirt As I suspected in your original comment, you missed the point of the question when you downvoted. OP was **not** looking for a full install of Android Studio (which is what you're detailing in your article), OP was only looking for the **SDK tools**, which **does not** have an installation GUI.

Comment: Yes Michael, you are right. I could not be successful to use the tools via cmd and gave up. For former releases I used them. I have also one more article on this usage. But this time, I will go with the full installation.

Answer (score 6):

You can download v24.4 installer like the good old day [here](http://filehippo.com/download_android_sdk/download/dd03cc329af0cd74b0e34afce1b4888e/). It will update itself to v25.x and everything works as expected.