# Quickest, least hassle way to get Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I want to target Android from Unity. I'll be teaching a class so want a fast and easy deployment of the SDK without messing with 30 students' different laptop setups.

Is it possible to download just the Android SDK for a given OS without going via intermediaries (SDKManager, Studio etc)? Where can it be found and are any installation steps required?

EDIT: Thanks to a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998252/unable-to-install-android-sdk-platform-tools-from-sdk-manager) and a close look at what Studio was doing when it installed suggests this link works for Windows:
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r26.0.2-windows.zip

Is there somewhere I can find a definitive list of such links? And is it sufficient just to grab and unzip this archive? Unfortunately I've installed Studio now so my environment is a bit hosed from a testing perspective...

UPDATE: I've now discovered that the Android SDK itself seems to require a full JDK installation (not just JRE). For that rather tangential reason it seems unlikely I can use this in my specific context.

I'd still be interested to know whether there's a place to grab the latest SDK as a direct download, in case I decide to try to repack these dependencies for my students.

Comment: Yes. Download the Standalone Tools & unzip to a folder, download the required platform on one computer via `sdkmanager`, copy the SDK folder including the downloaded platforms onto  the other laptops via USB etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android sdk tools standalone installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169817/android-sdk-tools-standalone-installer)

Comment: I don't want to use SDKManager, though, I just want a zip file. Unfortunately, SDKManager relies on a working JDK installation, which many of my students won't have. Fixing that in class is too time-consuming to consider.

Comment: Right, I wasn't sure whether Unity required a full working Android SDK directory or not. Either way, you can still sneaker-net the API from the `sdk/platforms` folder if you've downloaded it on one working machine? That way you're only reliant on one machine having a JDK installed.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering that -- I may try it and see. I still have a Windows/Mac issue but I guess I could borrow a Mac and repeat the process...