# download build tools for Android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools, build-tools

I have Android studio 2.3.2 installed.
I have installed the sdk tools and platform tools manually because I'm in syria.
I really need to download the sdk build tools from another server because iadl is missing.
Is there is anyway​ to download this from external site?
My sdk is 25.0.2
My OS Linux mint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.de/p/android-sdk-build-tools.html
Don't know if those are official. I Hope so.

Here is a description with the official sdkmanager
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19416222/2145395

```
sdkmanager "build-tools"
```

does install the tools package.

Comment: The website itself is not official but the links to the downloads are from Google's official repository.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of all files for android sdk that you can download it without any error:
https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/AndroidSDK/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).