# How to Install Android SDK commandline tool for Flutter upgrade error?

Tags: flutter, android-sdk-tools

How to install Android SDK commandline tool on a Ubuntu remote server which doesn't have Display/GUI.
When I run, 'flutter upgrade' it gives me the below and I wanted to know if I can use Android SDK commandline tool for resolving the issue.

```
$flutter upgrade                                                                                
Upgrading Flutter from /home/yvelumani/flutterDev/sdk/flutter...  
Building flutter tool...`

Upgrading engine...
Downloading Android Maven dependencies...
Failed to download the Android dependencies
Downloading Android Maven dependencies...                         127.7s (!)

Flutter 1.22.0-10.0.pre.133 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git  
Framework • revision 577de1c44e (46 minutes ago) • 2020-09-10 15:55:03 -0700  
Engine • revision fee6f9e533  
Tools • Dart 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-110.0.dev)

Running flutter doctor...   
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):  
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.22.0-10.0.pre.133, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)  
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices   
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.  
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html  
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.  
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).  
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to that location.  
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

    ✗ Android SDK file not found: adb.  
[!] Android Studio (not installed)  
[✓] Proxy Configuration  
[!] Connected device  
    ! No devices available  

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

I have downloaded android SDK commandline tool from https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools. But I am not sure how to install this tool and what path to be chosen as ANDROID_HOME?

NOTE: I am not going/able to use Android Studio for my app development.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Did you try this answer?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963508/how-to-install-android-sdk-build-tools-on-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio >> Tools >> SDK Manager >> SDK Tools >> Android SDK Command Line Tools