# Is there a way we can download Sdk Command line tools from terminal in Linux?

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, sdk, command-line-interface

The query is, whether Without Android Studio or SDK Manager GUI is there a way to download SDK command-line tools from the terminal in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly install Java

```
$ sudo yum install java-11-openjdk-devel
```

If you are using EC2 Instance then

```
$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11
```

Create folder named "android" or "Android"

```
$ mkdir android
$ cd android
```

Then download commandline tools

```
$ wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-8512546_latest.zip
```

Unzip the folder using below command,

```
$ unzip commandlinetools-linux-8512546_latest.zip
```

Now create directory named 'latest' in command-line tools

```
$ cd cmdline-tools/
$ ls
     bin  lib  NOTICE.txt  source.properties
$ mkdir latest
```

Move mentioned packages in latest directory

```
$ mv bin/ lib/ NOTICE.txt source.properties latest/
```

Command to check the version

```
$ cd cmdline-tools/latest/bin/
$ ./sdkmanager --version
```

Answer (score 0):

So... read carefully, if you don't understand, check the last part...

By default, the SDK Manager from the command line does not include the build tools in the list. They're in the "obsolete" category. To see all available downloads, use

`android list sdk --all`

And then to get one of the packages in that list from the command line, use:

`android update sdk -u -a -t <package no.>`

Where -u stands for --no-ui, -a stands for --all and -t stands for --filter.

If you need to install multiple packages do:

`android update sdk -u -a -t 1,2,3,4,..,n`

Where 1,2,..,n is the package number listed with the list command above

**I found this answer from other question, In here you can find more information:[How to install Android SDK Build Tools on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963508/how-to-install-android-sdk-build-tools-on-the-command-line)