# Gradle : How to automatically install CMake

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on an Android native project which builds using `CMake`.
In my `build.gradle` I specify :

```
if(project.hasProperty("native")) {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                path file('jni/CMakeLists.txt')
                version '3.18.1+'
            }

        }
    }
```

I want to invoke `externalNativeBuild` task from command-line only on an automated build server.
However I am getting this error:

```
CMake '3.18.1' or higher was not found in SDK, PATH, or by cmake.dir property.
```

When I build it inside `Android Studio` normally, It downloads and install `CMake` but it is not happening from command-line.
Is there a way to do it from command-line?

Comment: What package is the CMakeLists.txt file in?

Comment: CMakeLists.txt is in root-prject/app/jni folder. build.gradle is in root-prject/app

Comment: path file('jni/CMakeLists.txt') to path file('CMakeLists.txt') changed.

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: Still not sure how to do this from within stock Gradle but [com.quittle.setup-android-sdk](https://github.com/quittle/gradle-setup-android-sdk) seems to work if you're willing to tolerate a 3rd-party plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio will automatically create a `local.properties` file which contains the `cmake.dir` property.

When you build on the build server, it's more than likely that you your source doesn't have a `local.properties` file as that file is not normally checked into code repositories.  You'll either need to create this file or modify the `PATH` environment variable to include the `cmake` binary.  This of course presumes that you have CMake installed on the build server. You can do this manually with a .zip/.tarball or if you have access to the SDK on the build server, you can install with the build tools -> [How to install Android SDK Build Tools on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963508/how-to-install-android-sdk-build-tools-on-the-command-line)

Comment: Shouldn't android gradle plugin automatically install cmake(https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#install_ndk_and_cmake_automatically)?

Comment: "if their licenses have been accepted in advance".  This assumes that you're using plugin 4.2.0+, you've actually accepted the licenses on the server with the appropriate sdkmanager, your build is using said sdkmanager, and that your build server has access to the Internet so that it can pull it in automatically.

Comment: It is automatically installing NDK but not cmake. do I need to change anything specific for cmake?

Comment: Did you accept the licenses for CMake?   In a pinch, you can manually install CMake with `yes | ./sdkmanager --install "cmake;<your version>"`

Comment: Is there a way to do it in gradle file instead of doing it on commandline

Comment: Yes, you can run any arbitrary command in gradle with the `exec` task, but that's just a band aide.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#download-with-gradle