# Can not install android sdk 22.2.1

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

Part 1

I downloaded the latest version of Eclipse from [Get the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).
After installing everything a message saying 'This version of ADT requires Android SDK Tools revision 22.2.1 or above, current revision is 20.0.0 Please update you SDK Tools to the latest version'.

Thinking I had made a mistake, I found a link [SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html), that lead me to [Get the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). And I downloaded everything again, and set it all up again. But it still had revision 20.0.0 in the SDK Manager.

I then looked for 22.2.1 elsewhere and found [Tech Spot: Android SDK 22.2.1](http://www.techspot.com/downloads/5425-android-sdk.html). But even this new version when it is loaded into the SDK manager comes up as revision 20.0.0.

My brother had a solution to this problem. It was buy a Mac Book Pro and start making apps for Apple. But before I finally give up on Android, I thought I'd try and resolve this problem, just for fun.

Any Ideas out there as to why revision 20 keeps coming up in the SDK manager?

Part 2

In the SDK manager, I pressed 'Tools' and then 'About'. And it said the current version of the SDK manager is in fact 22.2.1. So it's not the manager but the actual SDK tools that are revision 20.

Comment: Yes, buy a mac, because spending 2000$ on a machine just because you can't install an SDK makes sense.    Uninstall EVERYTHING and try again, or go get android studio and use that.

Comment: So in the SDK manager it does not specify "update available" for the Android SDK tools? Also this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869929/update-android-sdk-tool-to-22-0-4latest-version-from-22-0-1

Comment: I thought the MAC comment was funny, so I added it for fun. I am looking at Android studio right now. And the SDK manager doesn't specify "update available"

Comment: I am now downloading Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks [ashatte](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1421144/ashatte), I'm still downloading [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Updating), but will do what [Bhavesh Patadiya](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869929/update-android-sdk-tool-to-22-0-4latest-version-from-22-0-1) did in the link you provided. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks hopefully you work it out!

Comment: @ashatte I just did what Bhavesh Patadiya said but I still can't find the 22.2.1 tools. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

I mastered xcode (well sort of). At least I got it working and published an app or two. This Eclipse/Android) however, by way of contrast is the pits. I keep going backwards. I am at least six generations back from the original problem. This is just a comment.