# Android 4.4 ( KITKAT ) API LEVEL 19 is not listed in Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

As its apparent that *`Android 4.4 ( KITKAT ) API Level: 19`* is now available.

I just want to update to the latest API Level and then change the `android:targetSdkVersion="19"`
in the manifest file.

I clicked on `Android SDK Manager` using `Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers` having `Version: Helios Service Release 2.`

The Android SDK Manager opened but I didn't found `Android API Level: 19` in the list of Packages.

Further I saw other SO posts mentioning that if you clear the cache under `Tools -> Options` in Android SDK Manager and reload the Android SDK Manager then you will get this API listed in packages.

I did the same but no luck.

**The screenshot below-**

[image]

Comment: You are using the tools preview channel. Try switching back to the regular tools. You are missing several entries, just in what's visible in your screenshot.

Comment: @CommonsWare- How to switch back to the `regular tools` in Android SDK Manager ? I didn't found any such option listed there. However, there is one option `Enable Preview Tools` that was already checked, so I unchecked it and reloaded the Manager but still API Level 19 not listed.

Comment: I have never used the tools preview channel, so I have no idea how to revert it. However, if you look at your screenshot, you will see "Tools" and "Tools (Preview Channel)". You have "Android SDK Tools" in "Tools (Preview Channel)" installed, and you do not have "Android SDK Tools" in "Tools" installed.

Comment: @CommonsWare- But long time back I updated to Android API Level 17 without any problems with the same settings. Still, using the `tools preview channel` is the problem ?

Comment: I do not know that it is the problem. However, it is something that is unusual about your environment. This is why I suggested that you **try** switching back to the regular tools.

Comment: See if there's an update for the SDK manager (`Help`->`Check for updates`). Also you might consider upgrading Eclipse to Kepler. Helios is kind of ancient ;-)

Comment: @VedPrakash, Check Show Installed Packages (Packages>Show Installed Packages) Then the Android 4.4 (API 19) option is displayed on Android SDK Manager Rev 22.3

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena- This option is already checked in my `Android SDK Manager`. That is why I seeing the list of installed packages as you see in the screenshot.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel- Thanks, Updating the "Android SDK Tools" worked in showing the API 19.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upgrading to latest **"Android SDK tools"** was the solution although that was not straight forward and required a little tweak. It required to first update the ADT.

Once the ADT was updated, I reloaded the **"Android SDK Manager"**. 
Now, there was no Tools preview channel listed as installed in Android SDK Manager and reloading the Manager asked for either to install **"Tools"** OR **"Tools(Preview Channel)"**.

I did the install for **"Tools"** and it worked.

Meanwhile, the link helpful to sort out the problem was -

[Update Android SDK Tool to the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869929/update-android-sdk-tool-to-22-0-4latest-version-from-22-0-1).

During process, it was giving `timed out error` and there was no direct update allowed.

So, as mentioned in the linked post, I first updated the ADT to the latest and then I 
installed the **"SDK Tools"** for the recently updated ADT.

Then once I get the recent **"SDK Tools"**, it was all set.

Since it was the new install of ADT, so there was no **"Tools (Preview Channel)"** already installed as was before. However, it is now your choice what Tool you want to install. I installed **"Tools"**.

Then I reloaded the **"Android SDK Manager"** and API 19 appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by clicking "Packages -> Reload".