# Not able to download the Android ADT version 21 with SDK 21

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

I am able to download the ADT 21 but not able to download SDK 21. The only version i am able to download is 22.x (latest version) but for my project i am required only SDK 21.
Every time i open eclipse under preferences it gives me error "This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.2 or above.  Current version is 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525.  Please update ADT to the latest version."

Where can i download the Android ADT version 21 with SDK 21.

Thanks.

Comment: pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869929/update-android-sdk-tool-to-22-0-4latest-version-from-22-0-1

Comment: Hi Nithinlal, i am already following the same procedure, but it is downloading the latest SDK tools only 22.x. I am required 21 only.

Comment: Follow the steps : Help -> Install New Software -> Add -> (Give any name suppose NewUpdate) -> add this url : https://dl-ssl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 -> OK

Now it will list the available updates, which should ideally be adt 20.x.x

Select the list items Let it be installed. Eclipse will restart and Its done.

I hope this will helpful for you :)

Comment: I tried this, it is showing Developer Tools version 22.6.3. :(

Comment: continue the installation .I think Android ADT version 21 not available now.

Comment: well i am able to download the ADT 21 from here: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-21.0.0.zip but the problem is downloading the compatible tools. It is only downloading the latest tools. I need the compatible tools for ADT 21. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55360/discussion-between-usman-and-nithinlal).