# How do I download the latest version of the Android SDK?

Tags: android, adt

Yes yes it's here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

But I forgot to mention I'm not using Firefox, or IE, or Safari, or even (shocked gasp) Chrome.

I'm using KDE rekonq, which, although technically a WebKit browser, does not inspire that over-developed site to list anything under "Choose the SDK package for your OS from the table below."

That's right. Where you see the clicker for your least-favorite OS in that "table", I see *absolutely nothing*. The website does not recognize my rekonq, and does not pop in the link for the Linux version. Worse, the website does not simply barf out *every* version, responding to the edge-case where it cannot detect *any* of them.

So, while I download http://dl.google.com/android/archives/android-sdk-linux_x86-1.6_r1.tgz expecting to then tell it to upgrade itself, would anyone like to try to answer the meta-question, here; how I was expected to download the LATEST version despite using an inferior browser?

(And we will next discuss the ethics & accessibility of a CAPTCHA system that shells to YouTube...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the

ANDROID STUDIO :   http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

or

ADT BUNDLE : http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

this bundle has all what you would be required download it extract it and you are good to go !!

Comment: Okay, THIS time the page http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html (please read my first sentence again) has a clicker for the SDK for Linux. Maybe I hit the page too often or something.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?
If you are using Eclipse, you can install the ADT directly from Eclipse

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

In Eclipse
Help > Install New Software
In add repository, enter the URL: 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
Select the developer tools.

Develop!

Comment: Eclipse keeps asking where the SDK already is, to install it. It's this bug, but for Ubuntu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894929/location-of-the-android-sdk-has-not-been-setup-in-the-preferences-in-mac-os (And I have installed Android before on both Ubuntu and Win7, without all these problems.) But my main question is about the bug in Android's website.

Answer (score 0):

**ADT (Eclipse)**:

`Help -> Check for Updates`

All the available updates including **Android SDK** will be automatically displayed. I updated my **Android SDK** to version **22.3** yesterday by following the above steps.

Comment: Already checked for updates; that did not get around the bug where Eclipse refused to DL the SDK for me.

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Nope. The irony is I've been playing with the Android SDK recreationally since 2006, and devving full time since this summer, and I have _never_ had so many platform issues as this install session. Blame the 64-bit KUbuntu...

Answer (score 0):

ADT (Eclipse):

Help -> Check for Updates

All the available updates including Android SDK will be automatically displayed.

OR

you can install the ADT directly from Eclipse

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html